# SIZE_MAX not declared when trying to build opencv-2.4.10 on raspbian wheezy

Tags: opencv, raspbian-wheezy

I'm trying to build opencv-2.4.10 on my Raspberry Pi model B (wheezy) following [these instructions](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/) but am getting the error below.  What's the best way of fixing this?

`[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/jasper/jasper.h:77:0,
                 from /home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/modules/highgui/src/grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:58:
/usr/include/jasper/jas_math.h: In function ‘int jas_safe_size_mul(size_t, size_t, size_t*)’:
/usr/include/jasper/jas_math.h:117:22: error: ‘SIZE_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/build.make:422: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1772: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:133: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if its best practice but after trying to correct by defining __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS, I gave up and edited /usr/include/jasper/jas_math.h, adding

```
#if ! defined SIZE_MAX
#define SIZE_MAX (4294967295U)
#endif
```

right after

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

Comment: It's certainly not best practice ... that would be to submit a solution back to the (assumed open source) root of the problem.  But I recognise it as common practice :-)

Comment: it's not a good way. [How to get SIZE_MAX in C89](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44401965/995714)