# opencv-3.0.0 install error on centos7

Tags: opencv, installation, centos7

I download opencv-3.0.0.zip and unzip it , then execute：

```
 #cd opencv-3.0.0/
 #mkdir build
 #cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./build -D  WITH_IPP=OFF ../opencv-3.0.0
 #make -j8
```

and it make some error :

```
 ……

[ 49%] Building CXX object 
modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/src/grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/jasper/jasper.h:77:0,
                 from /home/apps/zhimin.feng/software/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:59:
/usr/include/jasper/jas_math.h: In function ‘bool jas_safe_size_mul(size_t, size_t, size_t*)’:
/usr/include/jasper/jas_math.h:143:15: error: ‘SIZE_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
if (x && y > SIZE_MAX / x) {
           ^
/usr/include/jasper/jas_math.h: In function ‘bool jas_safe_size_add(size_t, size_t, size_t*)’:
/usr/include/jasper/jas_math.h:170:10: error: ‘SIZE_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
 if (y > SIZE_MAX - x) {
      ^
make[2]: *** [modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/src/grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I might have install all the dependency ,but it still occur the error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fail in the yum installed version of jasper. Currently the best thing to do is to downgrade from the updates version released on 15/5/2017 (Release 30.el7) back to the base package version (Release 29.el7)

I've created a ticket [here](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=13276). In the meantime running

`sudo yum install jasper-devel-1.900.1-29.el7` instead of `sudo yum install jasper-devel` should do the trick

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the answer from

[SIZE_MAX not declared when trying to build opencv-2.4.10 on raspbian wheezy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915286/size-max-not-declared-when-trying-to-build-opencv-2-4-10-on-raspbian-wheezy)

edit /usr/include/jasper/jas_math.h,add

```
#if ! defined SIZE_MAX
#define SIZE_MAX (4294967295U)
#endif
```

after

```
#include <stdint.h>
```